# Loading & unloading for $(location).attr('href',url) function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this function `downloadcsv()` function it takes 30sec to download .csv file in the meantime, we try do loading and unloading to the function  how can we do this

```
<a class="dwnload-cv" onclick="downloadcsv('latecomerrpt');" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download CSV
    </span>
</a>


function downloadcsv(tagname) {
    $(location).attr('href','download.php?act='+tagname+'&'+$("#search").serialize());
}
```

Comment: can you check it ````let data=$(location).attr('href','download.php?act='+tagname+'&'+$("#search").serialize()); console.log(data)````  , how much time it is taking to console data

Comment: it depends on no.of days data they are downloading. minimal days it goes to 30sec max it goes up to 2 to 3mins @DEEPAK